# In a quiz contest,probabilities of teachers,boy students and girl students answering the question correctly are $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$...

Tags: probability

In a quiz contest,probabilities of teacher,boy students and girl students answering the question correctly are $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$ respectively.The probability of teacher and student agreeing to the same answer is $\dfrac12$.Find the ratio of the number of boy students to the girl students.

My work:
There arise two cases when they agree-
*(1)* The teacher and the student are correct.
*(2)* The teacher and the student are wrong.

Case *(1)* has two subcases-
*(i)* The teacher and the male student are correct.
*(ii)* The teacher and the female student are correct.

Case *(2)* has two subcases-
*(i)* The teacher and the male student are wrong.
*(ii)* The teacher and the female student are wrong.

From this we can get,
$\alpha \beta+(1-\alpha)(1-\beta)+\alpha \gamma+(1-\alpha)(1-\gamma)=\dfrac12$

Now, I consider that there are total $n$ students and I consider there are $k$ male students. I need to find out the ratio $k:n-k$. But I cannot proceed further. Please help.

Comment: @TooTone Yes, I was thinking of the intersecting event too.

Answer (score 3):

Assume $0 < \alpha < 1.$ Let the number of boys be $b,$ the number of girls be $g,$ and the desired ratio be $x={b/g}.$ If $\alpha$ is unequal to ${1 \over 2},$ the restriction that the teacher agrees with the students with probability $1 \over 2$ can be expressed as $${1 \over 2}= { {\beta b + \gamma g} \over {b+g}}$$ Now divide both numerator and denominator of the right hand side by $g.$ Then we have $${1 \over 2}= { {\beta x + \gamma} \over {x+1} }$$ Solving for $x,$ we find $$x = { {2 \gamma - 1} \over {1- 2 \beta} } $$ In the case for $\alpha = {1 \over 2},$ then the ratio of boys to girls could be anything.

Comment: On second thought, I don't think my first equation is correct. I have to rethink it.

Comment: OK, I have created 2 cases depending on the value of $\alpha.$ Try it out.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the question. Your result (when $\alpha \ne \frac12$) is independent of $\alpha$, but that can't possibly be true. Consider for instance the two extremes $\alpha = 0$ and $\alpha = 1$.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming $\alpha > 0$ and $\alpha < 1.$ I've added that in to my solution.

Comment: I now think that the question is ill-posed. So it's not surprising that we disagreed on its solution.

Comment: Could be. On a previous attempt I thought the condition was that the teacher's probability of being correct was equal to the students' probability of being correct. But it is not stated that way, so I redid it based on the current wording.

Comment: I changed my mind - the question is OK. (But your answer isn't $-$ it should still depend on $\alpha$.)

Comment: One would think so. However, it eventually became apparent to me that if the student probability of being correct is ${1 \over 2},$ then the restriction is met regardless of $\alpha.$ That is the origin of my first equation.

Answer (score 2):

> In a quiz contest,probabilities of teacher,boy students and girl students answering the question correctly are α, β and γ respectively.

I think the only way this question is tractable is if you assume independence between teacher and students getting the answer correct.

> The probability of teacher and student agreeing to the same answer is $\frac12$.

I interpret this as meaning choosing any student randomly, the probability that that the teacher and student agree is $\frac12$.

> Find the ratio of the number of boy students to the girl students.

Let $b,g$ be the probabilities of being a boy or a girl.

By the theorem of total probability, $\mathbb{P}$(agree) = $\mathbb{P}$(agree|student is boy)$\;b$ + $\mathbb{P}$(agree|student is girl)$\;g$.

And as you wrote, the probability of agreeing is in each case (again by the theorem of total probability) the probability of both being correct + the probability of both being wrong. Hence

$$\begin{align}
(\alpha\beta + (1-\alpha)(1-\beta))b + (\alpha\gamma + (1-\alpha)(1-\gamma))g &= \frac{1}{2} \\\\
(\alpha\beta + (1-\alpha)(1-\beta))b &= \frac{1}{2} - (\alpha\gamma + (1-\alpha)(1-\gamma))g \\\\
(\alpha\beta + (1-\alpha)(1-\beta))b &= \frac{1 -2(\alpha\gamma + (1-\alpha)(1-\gamma))g}{2} \\\\
\end{align}$$

This can be solved by using the fact that $b = (1-g)$: see [TonyK's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/679909/77151) for the rest of the story.

Comment: Hang on $-$ how can you deduce $\frac{b}{g}$ from an equation of the form $rb = \frac12 - sg$? I think the question is flawed.

Comment: Your final equation assumes that the first term on the right-hand side of the previous equation is $\frac12g$, not $\frac12$.

Comment: Aha $-$ we can solve this using the condition $b+g=1$. See my answer.

Comment: @TonyK doh! I despair of my algebra sometimes!!! I'm gonna need to fix that...

Answer (score 2):

Starting from (i.e. stealing) TooTone's equation:

$$(\alpha\beta + (1-\alpha)(1-\beta))b = \frac{1}{2} - (\alpha\gamma + (1-\alpha)(1-\gamma))g$$

we can write it as $rb=\frac12 - sg$, and together with the further condition $b+g=1$, we get $rb=\frac12 - s(1-b)$, or

$$b = \frac{1-2s}{2(r-s)}$$

Similarly,

$$g = \frac{1-2r}{2(s-r)}$$

Hence

$$\frac{b}{g} = \frac{1-2s}{2r-1}$$

Writing this all out:

$$\frac{b}{g}=\frac{1-2(\alpha\gamma + (1-\alpha)(1-\gamma))}{2(\alpha\beta + (1-\alpha)(1-\beta))-1}$$

This is undefined if $r=s=\frac12$. In that case, the boy/girl ratio is undetermined.

Comment: thanks for the attribution -;)

Comment: As far as I can tell, this produces the same answers as my solution. What am I missing in my solution?

Comment: Right back at you! Nice try, but I can reduce your answer to mine with algebra. You think yours is dependent on $\alpha,$ but it is not!

Comment: Well I'm blowed. You are absolutely right. I apologise profusely!

Comment: No problem. This one's been beating me up for several days.

Comment: @soakley Me too, I had an abortive attempt a couple of days ago before starting again yesterday. I like the logic of your first equation -- it's an Occam's razor approach.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's worth noting that your and TonyK's work also produced the solution. I have the utmost respect for both of you.