# Probability question from British Math Olympiad, 1973

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Recently I got a problem from British Math Olympiad, 1973
It is a probability question.

> In answering general knowledge questions (framed so that each question is answered yes or no), the teacher's probability of being correct is $\alpha$ and a pupil's probability of being correct is $\beta$ or $\gamma$ according to as the pupil is a boy or a girl. 
>   The probability of a randomly chosen pupil agreeing with the teacher's answer is $\dfrac{1}{2}$. 
>   Find the ratio of a number of boys to girls in the class.

I did it as
$$b=\text{Number of boys}$$
$$g=\text{Number of girls}$$
so
$$\frac{1}{2}=\Big(\alpha \beta+(1-\alpha)(1-\beta)\Big)\Bigg(\dfrac{b}{b+g}\Bigg)+\Big(\alpha \gamma+(1-\alpha)(1-\gamma)\Big)\Bigg(\dfrac{g}{b+g}\Bigg)$$
$$\frac{b+g}{2}=\Big(\alpha \beta+(1-\alpha)(1-\beta)\Big)b+\Big(\alpha \gamma+(1-\alpha)(1-\gamma)\Big)g$$
divide by g
$$\frac{b+g}{2g}=\Big(\alpha \beta+(1-\alpha)(1-\beta)\Big)\Bigg(\dfrac{b}{g}\Bigg)+\Big(\alpha \gamma+(1-\alpha)(1-\gamma)\Big)\Bigg(\dfrac{g}{g}\Bigg)$$
$$\frac{b}{2g}+\frac{1}{2}=\Big(\alpha \beta+(1-\alpha)(1-\beta)\Big)\Bigg(\dfrac{b}{g}\Bigg)+\Big(\alpha \gamma+(1-\alpha)(1-\gamma)\Big)$$
$$\frac{b}{2g}-\Big(\alpha \beta+(1-\alpha)(1-\beta)\Big)\Bigg(\dfrac{b}{g}\Bigg)=\Big(\alpha \gamma+(1-\alpha)(1-\gamma)\Big)-\dfrac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{b}{g}=\dfrac{\Big(\alpha \gamma+(1-\alpha)(1-\gamma)\Big)-\dfrac{1}{2}}{\dfrac{1}{2}-\Big(\alpha \beta+(1-\alpha)(1-\beta)\Big)}$$

Is it right? Need Suggations.

Comment: What have you tried?  Show your effort!

Comment: I just update this as what I did to solve this.

Comment: is my answer, right? or any mistake @MartinKochanski

Comment: Perfect except for the last line! That final factor of $b/g$ should not appear in the denominator on the right. Though I **think** that you may also have changed a sign somewhere along the way, because it looks to me as if you have made the ratio negative.

Comment: Put $\beta=\gamma$, you get -1, instead of 1. Check the sign.

Comment: I checked it buy I don't find any algebraic mistake. Please point out my mistake by editing it @Macavity

Comment: Your question is answered in this older post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675178/in-a-quiz-contest-probabilities-of-teachers-boy-students-and-girl-students-answe?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

The probability that a randomly selected child gets the same answer as the teacher can be broken up by total probability as

$\Pr(B)\bigl(\alpha \beta + (1-\alpha)(1-\beta)\bigr) + \bigl(1-\Pr(B)\bigr)\bigl(\alpha\gamma + (1-\alpha)(1-\gamma)\bigr)$

Where $B$ is the event that our randomly selected child is a boy.  Make sure you understand why.

Comment: I wanted to write this answer, but I wasn't sure if there is a way to assume that the answer of the student is not independent of the answer of the teacher. Do you think we can factor that in as well?

Comment: @Alt that is a fair point.  In real life, that is not a safe assumption at all.  But, if we were to not assume that, then the expression becomes even worse.  The first half of it becoming $Pr(B)(\alpha Pr(\text{child correct}\mid \text{teacher correct})+(1-\alpha)Pr(\text{child incorrect}\mid \text{\teacher incorrect}))$ and the value of $\beta$ and $\gamma$ wouldn't even appear in the result and so didn't deserve to even be mentioned in the problem statement.

Comment: I just updated my question as what I did to solve this. Please check. is that right? @JMoravitz